# Floating divs not wrapping properly

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a bunch of divs set to float. For some reason, when it gets to 3 rows of floating divs, the divs start acting funny. Here's the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/grem28/nq1q55bz

It seems to have something to do with the names I have set. Here's the code:

```
<div class="pdfs">
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" /><br />AccuDrop</a>
</div>

<div class="pdfs">
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" /><br />AccuPen Vet</a>
</div>

<div class="pdfs">
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" /><br />Accutome Vet</a>
</div>

<div class="pdfs">
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" /><br />Connect Platform Catalog</a>
</div>

<div class="pdfs">
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" /><br />Instrument Care and Handling</a>
</div>

<div class="pdfs">
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" /><br />Opti-Kleen Diamond Knife Cleaning System</a>
</div>

<div class="pdfs">
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" /><br />Portables Brochure</a>
</div>

<div class="pdfs">
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" /><br />Surgical Disposable Catalog</a>
</div>

<div class="pdfs">
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" /><br />PachPen Study</a>
</div>

<div class="pdfs">
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" /><br />AccuPen Paper</a>
</div>

<div class="pdfs">
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" /><br />Femtosecond Cataract Instruments</a>
</div>
```

Here's the css:

```
.pdfs {
  width:22%;
  margin-right:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  float:left;
}

.pdfs:after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}

.pdfs img {width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your `:after` rule is there for, but I'd replace it with:

```
.pdfs:nth-child(4n+5) {
    clear:both
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nq1q55bz/4/)**

Comment: I found the code for floating divs somewhere. No idea what the :after did. Can you explain why this works?

Comment: Sure, you need to clear the divs being floated in order for the first one on the next row to make it all the way to the left, otherwise they're all floated and the one you want to be the leftmost will get stuck essentially on the text of one above it when it's longer than one of the other lines after it. This code just makes sure to clear the float on every row's first div. If you put borders on your divs you'll see how the text that hangs lower can cause a div after it to get hung up on it. Clearing the 4nth+5 div will force it to the next line.

Comment: how's it know when it's a 1st div and what's the 4n+5 thing about?

Comment: Since you set the width to 22%, only four divs will fit on a row, so you want to clear every fifth div. The 4n+5 rule starts at n=0, so this will add a clear:both to the 5th, 9th, 13th, etc elements. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child for a longer explanation of nth-child.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the float property at the end of every row. The funny activity is due to the uneven heights of some of the rows.

Adding `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` after every third div will solve the problem. The disadvantage is that it forces three items per row regardless of the window size. It's basically a way to denote the end of each row.